# How to interpret dependency on order for 1/3-octave band filters in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, butterworth

I am trying to obtain a third-octave band representation of the frequency content of an acoustic signal, obtained by numerical simulation. The signal is the following:

[image]

The code I use (you can reproduce it by replacing P and t with other signals):

```
P  = PNL(:,3) ;               % Acoustic pressure signal
t  = timeWindow ;             % Time array

T  = t(end) - t(1) ;          % Signal duration
fs = length(t)/T ;            % = 98123 [Hz]

T0 = 1 ;                      % Reference duration of 1 [s]

filterOrder        = 6 ;

allANSIFrequencies = getANSICenterFrequencies(octaveFilter('FilterOrder', filterOrder, 'Bandwidth', '1/3 octave', 'SampleRate', fs));  

cf = allANSIFrequencies(19 : 50) ;  % Restricting the frequency range to [15 Hz - 20000 Hz]

for k = 1 : length(cf)

   octFilt = octaveFilter(cf(k), 'Bandwidth', '1/3 octave','SampleRate', fs, 'FilterOrder', filterOrder, 'Oversample', false);
    
   y = octFilt(P);

   Prms =  sqrt((1/T0) * trapz(t, y.^2)) ;   % Root mean square pressure level

   LE(k)    = 20 * log10(Prms/20e-6) ;       % [db] Sound Exposure Level
     
end

semilogx(cf, LE)
grid on
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)') ;
ylabel('L_{E} (dB)') ;
legend('Order 2', 'Order 4', 'Order 6', 'Order 12')
```

The frequency content I would expect based on experimental data is a mix of the results at different orders: up to 1000 [Hz] the levels from order 6 are correct, while from 1000 [Hz] onwards, it's the order 2 that describes best the frequency content.

[image]

I obtain very different results depending on the filter order I am using. To a certain degree that's normal. Higher orders should provide a sharper response of the filter, but I fail to interpret these results.
The resolution of the signal under investigation should be high enough (98123 [Hz]). Any idea of what the issue could be?

Thank you in advance, I'd appreciate any insight on this!

Comment: I am confused, do I understand correctly that this code you are presenting here should generate the figure with different orders? However, the filter order is not changed at all and only the center frequency? Have you tried to compare the different filter responses for different orders?

Comment: No, the code here does not produce the figure I posted. It's just a minimum working example that applies only one order

Comment: I wouldn’t consider this a minimum working example as t and P are not given. Nevertheless you should include the code which produces this graph with everything what is needed to do so. Additionally I recommend you to visualise the frequency response of the input signals and the filters too.